# Open source image management software for web?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, language-agnostic, image-management

I was looking for an standalone open source image management software for web use. Many CMSs have some kind of image management built-in but sharing images across several sites seems to be clumsy. I am looking for more centralized solution.

The feature list could be:

- image upload
- store original (full resolution)
- tagging/taxonomy
- EXIF data reading
- search
- resize/crop
- serve altered versions of images with caching
- web UI
- simple access control

Any tips for existing software (as is or with potential with modifications)?

Comment: This is somewhat border case whether this belongs to Stack Overflow but feel free to suggest alternative site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gallery is a very full featured tool that has everything on your list. PHP based and very easy to install on Linux or IIS http://gallery.menalto.com/

It's not designed to be used quite how I think you have in mind but there should be enough features that you can reuse.

Answer (score 2):

http://resourcespace.org/ Seems to match a lot of your requirements, and is specifically meant as an image manager for use in combination with other systems.